# TypeScript '...' does not exist on type 'typeof ...'

Tags: typescript, angular

I have this piece of code that whatever I try, I can not get passed the following error.

**Error:**
Property 'EmailValidator' does not exist on type 'typeof UserValidators'.

**Code:**

```
import {EMAIL_REGEX} from '../constants';
import {Control} from 'angular2/common';

export interface IUserValidators {
  EmailValidator(control: Control) : Object;
}

export class UserValidators implements IUserValidators {
  EmailValidator(control: Control) : Object {
    if (!control.value) {
      return {
        required: true
      };
    } else if (control.value) {
      if (!new RegExp(EMAIL_REGEX).test(control.value)) {
        return {
          invalid: true
        };
      }
    }
    return {};
  }
}
```

This is how I try to inject the EmailValidator:

```
this.fb.group({
      email: ['', UserValidators.EmailValidator]
});
```

Comment: The error is entirely correct.  That's an instance method; you need an instance.

Comment: Thanks SLaks, I forgot about it.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You should create an instance of this class to be able to access it, like this:

```
var userValidators : IUserValidators = new UserValidators();
userValidators.EmailValidator(ctrl);
```